# Any ideas on why I get "This document has no pages"?

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf, itext

I have a basic method

```
    public string PdfFriendlyHtml ( Guid pid, int vid, int sid )
    {
        string html = string.Empty;
        html += "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td>";
        html += "<p>blah blah blah</p>";
        html += "<p>blah blah blah</p>";
        html += "</td></tr>"; // end header row
        List<SurveyFullInfo> Surveys = new List<SurveyFullInfo>();
        for ( int k = 1; k <= sid; ++k )
        {
            Surveys.Add(new SurveyFullInfo
            {
                Title = this._Db.GetSurveyTitle(k),
                ViewModel = this._Db.GetAnswersByPartner(pid, k, vid),
                SectionAverages = this._Db.GetSectionAverages(pid, k, vid)
            });
        }
        foreach ( var Survey in Surveys )
        {
            html += "<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EDEDED\">"; // open survey title and traffic lights
            html += "<h1>" + Survey.Title + "</h1>"; // write title 
            html += "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">";
            foreach ( var S in Survey.SectionAverages )
            {
                RangeInfo Info = AnswersController.Ranges.First(I => I.Range.X <= S.AvgScore && S.AvgScore < I.Range.Y);
                html += "<tr><td><div valign=\"middle\" style=\"background-color:" + Info.ColorHex + ";height:20px;width:20px;\"></div></td>"
                      + "<td><h3>" + String.Format("{0}: {1}%", S.SectionTitle, S.AvgScore.ToString()) + "</h3>"
                      + "<p>" + Info.Text + "</p><td></tr>";


            }
            html += "</table></td></tr>"; // end survey title and traffic lights row
        }


        html += "</table>"; // end table
        return html;
    }
```

that, as far as I can tell, generates valid HTML and is called in the following method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult ToPdf ( Guid pid, int vid, int sid )
    {


        Byte[] bytes;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    var example_html = PdfFriendlyHtml(pid, vid, sid);
                    var example_css = @".headline{font-size:200%}";
                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Position = 0;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", "Test.pdf");
        }
        catch 
        {
            ms.Dispose();
            throw;
        }   

    }
```

but I get the yellow screen of  death with a stack trace

> [IOException: The document has no pages.]
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree() +1040
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close() +285
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close() +319
>   iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close() +76
>   iTextSharp.text.DocWriter.Dispose() +10

I've narrowed it down that it must have something to do with the HTML, given that if I change it to

```
    public string PdfFriendlyHtml ( Guid pid, int vid, int sid )
    {
       return "<p>Test</p>";
    }
```

it works.

I also tried

```
    public string PdfFriendlyHtml ( Guid pid, int vid, int sid )
    {
        return "<table><tr><td>Here's a cell</td><td>And here's another cell</td></tr></table>";
    }
```

and that worked to. So I can't figure out what it doesn't like about my real method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your inner `foreach` block has an incorrect `<td>` tag at the end that should be a `</td>` instead:

```
RangeInfo Info = AnswersController.Ranges.First(I => I.Range.X <= S.AvgScore && S.AvgScore < I.Range.Y);
html += "<tr><td><div valign=\"middle\" style=\"background-color:" + Info.ColorHex + ";height:20px;width:20px;\"></div></td>"
      + "<td><h3>" + String.Format("{0}: {1}%", S.SectionTitle, S.AvgScore.ToString()) + "</h3>"
      + "<p>" + Info.Text + "</p></td></tr>";
//                               ↑HERE↑
```

When I make that change everything compiles for me.